# Installed the PL2303 Driver in my Mac, but I still can not find the `tty.usbserial*` under `/dev`

Tags: macos, install

Installed the PL2303 Driver in my Mac, but I still can not find the `tty.usbserial*` under `/dev`.

I follow the [PL2303 Driver](http://www.prolific.com.tw/us/showproduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41) to install the `PL2303_MacOSX_1.6.1_20171018.zip` in my Mac.

I installed the pkg, and restarted my Mac, but there is a difference between the manual and mine:

The manual:

[image: The Manual]

Mine MacOS:

[image]

And the most important is, under the `/dev`, I can not find any `tty.usbserial*`:

```
$ ls tty.*
tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
```

---

**EDIT-01**

IDs in the manual:

```
Product ID: 0x2303
Vendor ID: 0x067b
```

My USB2.0-Ser!:

```
Product ID： 0x7523
Vendor ID：  0x1a86
```

---

**EDIT-02**

My macOS sierra version is `10.12.6 (16G1114)`.

---

**EDIT-03**

I tried install [CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html](http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html)

But, now if I insert the USB into my Mac, my Mac will restart with the error on screen:

> your computer will restarted because of a problem. Press a key or wait a few seconds to continue starting up.

and there is no `USB2.0-Ser!` now:

[image]

Comment: If you click on USB2.0-ser! on your mac does the product ID & vendor ID match the IDs listed in the manual?

Comment: They are different.

Comment: @Scottmeup Do you mean it did not install success? but I follow the manual.

Comment: It's a little unusual that the manual lists a different vendor ID to the device that's plugged in. The vendor ID for the device plugged in belongs to QinHeng Electronics http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids and the PID identifies it as a CH340 . I might try drivers for a CH340 instead if you can find them. Did the software & manual you have come with the cable, or did you look them up yourself?

Comment: I look for the `software & manual ` by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the driver for the prolific chipset AT-232 cable installed - VID 0x067b, PID 0x2303.

The device you have connected is not reporting as a prolific AT-232. The device you have connected is reporting as a QinHeng Electronics CH340 - VID 0x1a86, PID 0x7523.

I'd recommend trying the driver for the CH340 http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html

Comment: Seems there a serious error now, see my EDIT-03.

Comment: Thank you, Scottmeup, I ask the vendor for their newest version. then installed success.